# Supabase Storage: Unable to Connect after Unpause

Tags: supabase

7 days ago, my app has been paused due to inactivity. After restoring/unpausing the project all is well except the storage. I got 500 internal server error

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please open a ticket from https://supabase.help about any issues that are specific to the instance.